# pthread_create: cannot allocate memory

Tags: c, linux, sockets, pthreads

I wrote a small tcp server, which creates a new thread for each incoming connection:

```
while (server_running)
{
  client_sock = accept(server_sock,
                   (struct sockaddr *)&client_name,
                   &client_name_len);

  if(!server_running)
    break;
  if (client_sock == -1)
    continue;
  /* accept_request(client_sock); */
  if (pthread_create(&newthread , NULL, &accept_request, &client_sock) != 0)
    perror("pthread_create");
}
```

After about 380 successfull connections, the error message

> 'pthread_create:cannot allocate memory'

occurs on every new connection attempt. I really don't have a clue where this comes from, since `accept_request` runs properly. I also noticed that there are many connections with status `TIME_WAIT` during the run (I used `netstat` for this). So where could something be going wrong?

Comment: [MCVE], though this does not look good even from what little you've posted.

Comment: Do you ever close the connection & end the thread? Both are finite resources and it seems you're hitting the limit on threads...

Comment: Probably you do not free the resources of the thread at the end. You have to either detach the thread or join it, such that all memory that a thread uses is freed after he exits. In your case it would probably best to create the thread detached from the start.

Comment: I close client_sock at the end of accept_request

Comment: @user2224350 Sure, but do you dispose of the thread ? A thread consumes a lot of resources even if you exit/return from it, until you either call pthread_join() on the thread from somehwer else, or it is disposed automatically if the thread is detached. By default a thread  on llinux have 8 or 10 MB of stack memory. So 380 threads means you use nearly 4GB of virtual memory - which may mean you hit a limit.

Comment: Well, you are out of memory, the error message is clear. Post a [mcve] and we could help you in your probably memory leak.

Comment: Probably, you're running out of memory. Each thread has a default stack size of 10MB. There is an option to change the stack size. You probably don't need a stack that deep. I'd try 10kb.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When your thread exits, it still hangs around in memory. By default a thread on linux consumes 8 or 10MB of stack, so with 380 threads, you might use nearly 4GB of virtual memory - which might hit a limit on your system.

To have a thread be disposed when it is finished executing , you need to call `pthread_join()` on that thread, or you can make the thread a 'detached' thread. A detached thread will automatically be disposed when it ends execution. You can add

```
pthread_detach(pthread_self());
```

to the start of your `accept_request()` thread function to make it a detached thread.

As a side note, you have a race condition on the call to

```
 pthread_create(&newthread , NULL, &accept_request, &client_sock)
```

Here you pass &client_sock to the thread, a local variable. If you have 2 clients connecting to your server at almost the same time, the last one will overwrite the `client_sock` variable, and 2 of your threads will see the same file descriptor. You could e.g. rather do this:

```
int *new_fd = malloc(sizeof *new_fd);
*new_fd = client_sock;
pthread_create(&newthread , NULL, &accept_request, new_fd)
```

And make sure your accept_request thread `free()`'s the passed in argument.